# Why aren't links clickable on my 404 error page?

Tags: 404-error, links

I have created a custom 404 error page. However, the links are not clickable. The link to my site and a random 404 page is https://createandgo.com/error404page

Comment: Because you have a giant giphy embed sitting on top of them that's broken ( as in it won't load ), and broken ( as in it has position relative and zero height and a few other styling related issues ). You also have CSS styles that hide giphy embeds on 404 pages too. Check it in your browsers dev tools and you'll see this is a generic CSS issue

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have incorrect css being used on some divs within that page.

On that page a couple of divs down from the H1 deceleration you have a div with some inline css:

```
<div style="width: 100%;height: 0;padding-bottom: 56%;position: relative;">
```

You need to remove the padding-bottom:56%; so it is:

```
<div style="width: 100%;height: 0;position: relative;">
```

Then in you have some css on in that template inside the `<style></style>` tags of:

```
.above {
    margin-top: -580px;
}
```

You also need to remove that completely. Once you do that your issue will be gone and your content will be positioned properly.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Unfortunately, my rep score isn't high enough to upvote.

Comment: Hi Daniel, that's great news   :) No worries.
You should be able to accept this as answered. You do not need to up vote it    ;)